# Why do we need a Scanner Object for taking input in java

Tags: java, oop, stream

To print output we simply use System.out stream while to take input, we have to pass System.in in Constructor of a Scanner object and then use that object only.

Why is it so ? Why is there no direct method like System.in.nextInt() or something alike?

Comment: Why does it matter? The language was designed that way. The people on the committee or team that designed it made that decision. Someone somewhere also made the decision to name the language *Java*.

Comment: You should read the [`Scanner` class' documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). `Scanner#nextInt()` is a convenience method, you can easily read bytes from `System.in` without a `Scanner` object. Also, should the `System` class have every possible method for parsing input, or should another class handle that task and let `System` stick to what it's meant to do instead of being bloated.

Comment: You obviously can just use `System.in.read()`, so this question doesn't make much sense in the current state, since you don't need Scanner at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.in is simply an InputStream. A pretty generic interface designed many years ago. Changing this aspect would break a lot of existing code. So changing the type of System.in is a no go.

Adding the scanner methods to the stream would bloat the existing class on the other hand. Think of concepts such as single responsibility principle or segregation of concerns.

You see - good object oriented design is about having small classes that have *one* responsibility. Not two, not 5 or 10.

But I think you have a certain point - and if Java would be rewritten today, that input stream might end up being more convenient.

Comment: The word "bloat" also came to my mind in regard to including scanner methods.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner is a class which is defined in the standard Java Class Library, that you can use it to read from the console like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = sc.nextInt();
```

however there are even more options that this constructer can do, for example you can read from a file and not console like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));
  while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
      long aLong = sc.nextLong();
  }
```

so basically depending on the constructer you can choose where you want to read your input from.

Additionally, there are multiple ways to represent integers in a stream. `Scanner.nextInt()` reads them as a text string. [`DataInputStream.readInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) reads them as binary data.

If you mix them up, a human would enter `1234` and get `825373492`, or a computer would enter `825373492` and get `1234`. Both would be confused. By having to specify Scanner or DataInputStream, there are no such surprises or bugs, because you state up front what "read an integer" means.

Read this: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: "IDE standard library"? What is it?

Comment: In your Eclipse environment whenever you make a new project there is a standard library that contains classes like: Scanner, String, ArrayList and so on.

Comment: Man, it is called JDK. IDE does not contain any classes!

Comment: @ИгорьДобровольський The IDE can certainly provide classes -- a typical example from Eclipse is SWT. Scanner in particular is from the JCL though (not JDK).  Feel free to suggest edits when you believe you can make a post more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One important difference between `System.in` and `System.out` is, that - although both are streams - one is a more specialized stream. Look at the class' [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html):

*Field Summary*

```
static InputStream in
static PrintStream out
```

The counterpart of `InputStream` is an `OutputStream`, but the Java designers made the class variable `out` a `PrintStream`. This is the reason why you see more specialized methods for `System.out` than you do for `System.in`.

As for why this is the case, see @GhostCat's answer.